# Why is hl-line+.el not a package?

Tags: package-development, hl-line-mode, licensing

Apparently [`hl-line+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/hl-line%2b.el) solves certain performance problems of `hl-line-mode`.

It is created in 2006, and last updated in 2018.

Despite that, it was never packaged to be available at e.g. melpa, which would be a bit more convenient than copy-pasting updates from wiki into a local setup.

Is there any reason, e.g. license terms, that prevents someone from creating and maintaining such a package? For instance, I can neither understand the license under which the specific file is made available, nor can I understand under which license files at https://github.com/emacsmirror/emacswiki.org/ are published.

While at it: is there a much better alternative to `hl-line+` that makes it obsolete and not worth maintaining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was on MELPA. It's not on MELPA anymore because MELPA doesn't want to pull from Emacs Wiki anymore. It's on Emacs Wiki because that's where I prefer to upload it. And it is a "package" - a single library.

If you want to use it, just (1) download it from the wiki, (2) put it in a directory that's in your `load-path`, and (3) do `(require 'hl-line+)`.

There's nothing unusual about the license used for `hl-line+.el`. It's GNU GPL.

Comment: Thank you! The advantage of a package is easier installation and easier upgrade through the unified interface. So if somebody (e.g. me) made a package and uploaded it to e.g. Melpa, with proper attribution, it would be OK, I suppose?

Comment: See [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7vocqa/update_on_melpa_removing_emacswiki_packages_they/dtuhzmt/) and thread, about this topic generally and about mirroring my libraries. [Here](https://framagit.org/steckerhalter/highlight.el), for instance, is where `highlight.el` is mirrored.